# Unable to add platform and make build in ionic4 project

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, ionic4

I am trying to build an android app with ionic4. 
I am using this command :`ionic cordova prepare android`

Every time when I am going to add platform getting this error.

```
>     (node:22860) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): CordovaError
>     (node:22860) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are
> not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit
> code.
```

Here is the configuration in my machine:

- npm - 5.5.1
- node - 9.0.0
- ionic CLI - 4.1.0
- cordova - 8.0.0

Is  there is any compatibility issue?

Comment: how does your folder structure look like, do you have a platforms folder as well as an android folder?

Comment: Try installing node 10 or above